# Docker phpunit from alpine:3.7 enter shell CLI sh or bash

Tags: bash, shell, docker, phpunit, command-line-interface

I enter the shell CLI of [alpine:3.7](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/) this way

```
docker run -it -v $PWD:/app alpine:3.7 /bin/sh
```

and everything works fine but when I'm trying to enter the shell cli in this image [phpunit/phpunit](https://hub.docker.com/r/phpunit/phpunit/) here is its [Dockerfile](https://github.com/JulienBreux/phpunit-docker/blob/master/6.5.3/Dockerfile) where you may find:

> FROM alpine:3.7

all these attempts are not working:

```
docker run -it -v $PWD:/app phpunit/phpunit /bin/sh
docker run -it -v $PWD:/app phpunit/phpunit /bin/bash
docker run -it -v $PWD:/app phpunit/phpunit sh
docker run -it -v $PWD:/app phpunit/phpunit bash
```

i only get printed content of the binary file. It looks to me that even I specified /bin/sh it is treated as a parameter for the phpunit application rather than the application to run.

How to run shell CLI in the [phpunit/phpunit](https://hub.docker.com/r/phpunit/phpunit/) container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe phpunit/phpunit image defines the `phpunit` command as a custom entrypoint ([Dockerfile#L66](https://github.com/JulienBreux/phpunit-docker/blob/e34f558ea775f8c3edbce21b22c61f7a12ef3226/6.5.3/Dockerfile#L66)). So, your arguments (e.g., `/bin/sh`) are treated as arguments to phpunit. You should override the entrypoint if you want to run a shell instead of phpunit. Here's one way to do it.

```
docker container run -it -v $PWD:/app --entrypoint "" phpunit/phpunit sh
```